# How to convert values in a dictionary into a comma separated string, also the dictionaries are present inside a list

Tags: python

My input data is given below:

```
l =  [{u'lat': 57.161597, u'lng': -1.0962736},
      {u'lat': 32.3794617, u'lng': -0.0834768}]
```

I want to convert it into the following list:

```
l_1 = [{57.161597, -1.0962736},
       {32.3794617, -0.0834768}]
```

Can I also get the output as:

```
l_1 = ['57.161597, -1.0962736', '32.3794617, -0.0834768']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a try with [`list comprehension`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
k = [{u'lat': 57.161597, u'lng': -1.0962736}, {u'lat': 32.3794617, u'lng': -0.08347689999999999}]
l = [set(i.values()) for i in k]
print(l)
```

If you want the O/P in list of list then you can do like this :

```
l = [list(i.values()) for i in k]
```

***UPDATE :***

If you want flat list of string elements you can do like  this :

```
s = [','.join(map(str,i.values())) for i in k]
```

**O/P :**

```
['-1.0962736, 57.161597', '-0.08347689999999999, 32.3794617']
```

Comment: Why are you using `set`?

Comment: because the op wants the o/p in set format, if not using set it will return list of list.

Comment: O/P is unclear what they want. It looks like a dict but it can't be one hence I'd not assume he wants a set. Also, set would remove if both lng and lat are equal. I'm sure OP doesn't want that

Comment: @ThatBird I have added the options, so OP can choose according to his needs. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: can you help me in getting the output as a string inside a list e.g.  ['57.161597, -1.0962736', '32.3794617, -0.0834768']

Comment: @VikasDamodar, the updated code is returning a list inside a list, thank you! for that. But, I also need the output in string comma separated string format as well. I have given the example above.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [{'lat': 57.161597, 'lng': -1.0962736}, {'lat': 32.3794617, 'lng': -0.08347689999999999}]
>>> [set(d.values()) for d in l]
[{57.161597, -1.0962736}, {32.3794617, -0.08347689999999999}]
>>>
```

Comment: Your code is crashing, l is not defined. Also, if you use `set` and lat and lng are equal, you'll end up removing them.

Comment: Sorry.. That was a typo. FIxed it. If you dont want duplicates to be removed, you should consider using a list

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
In [12]: map(lambda x:set(x.values()),input_data)
Out[12]: [{-1.0962736, 57.161597}, {-0.08347689999999999, 32.3794617}]
```

As per your second suggestion for string.

```
In [21]: [','.join(map(str,i.values())) for i in input_data]
Out[21]: ['57.161597,-1.0962736', '32.3794617,-0.0834769']
```

OR

```
In [17]: map(lambda x:','.join(map(str,x.values())),input_data)
Out[17]: ['57.161597,-1.0962736', '32.3794617,-0.0834769']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this

```
>>>import re
>>>l_1 = re.sub(r"['lngat:]", "", str(l))
>>>print(l_1)
[{ -1.0962736,  57.161597}, { -0.0834768,  32.3794617}]
```